REGEX swapping format of capture groups
I am trying to write a replace regex that will swap between two parameter formats for two different programs
PL/SQL Developer wants variables to use &foo
Report Server wants variables to use ${foo}
(Strictly speaking RS supports a lot of variants of ${} but for my purpose i'm just swapping simple stuff)
\$\{([^}]+)\}|&([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*) captures two groups, one for each variable format
for replace text, I want to swap between them. So ${var} becomes &var and &var becomes ${var} again.
The problem then was that I have two capture groups, and always replace both, then I got stuck with extra characters
Like, if I have this
select ${My_parameter_0} from dual;
select ${My_parameter_1} from dual;
select &my_variable_2 from dual;
select &my_variable_3 from dual;

Then capture group 1 should be My_parameter_0/1 and capture group 2 should be my_variable_2/3
Seperately, is trivial to replace Group 1 with &$1 and Group 2 with ${$2}
...
Well, I know there's something wrong with my REGEX, as replacing with &$1${$2} eventually ends up with
select &&&&My_parameter_2${}${}${} from dual; funny, but not what I wanted

What programming language are you using? If the language allows you to use a function as the replacement value, it can test which alternative was matched and return the appropriate replacement.

You could try conditional substitution ${1:+&$1:\$\{$2\}} if you're using PCRE2 based regex.
